# bash tail on a live log file, counting uniq lines with same date/time

Tags: bash, logging, tail, uniq

I'm looking for a good way to tail on a live log file, and display number of lines with the same date/time.

Currently this is working:

```
 tail -F /var/logs/request.log | [cut the date-time] | uniq -c
```

BUT the performance is not good enough. There is a delay of more than one minute, and it output in bulks of few lines each time.

Any idea?

Comment: would you consider writing your own loop (bash script) that processes the output of `tail` and updates a counter until the date-time changes, then prints the count and resets the counter?

Comment: @Floris and that would help how?

Comment: Actually, what is the datetime format that goes into uniq?

Comment: @yaccz - it (explicit bash script to process lines from `tail` without passing through `cut` and `uniq`) is one way to bypass the problem of pipe buffering. But I found a (marginally) more direct way to do that… see answer below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your problem is most likely related to buffering in your system, not anything intrinsically wrong with your line of code. I was able to create a test scenario where I could reproduce it - then make it go away. I hope it will work for you too.

Here is my test scenario. First I write a short script that writes the time to a file every 100 ms (approx) - this is my "log file" that generates enough data that `uniq -c` should give me an interesting output every second:

```
#!/bin/ksh
while :
do
  echo The time is `date` >> a.txt
  sleep 0.1
done
```

(Note - I had to use `ksh` which has the ability to do a sub-second `sleep`)

In another window, I type

```
tail -f a.txt | uniq -c
```

Sure enough, you get the following output appearing every second:

```
   9 The time is Thu Dec 12 21:01:05 EST 2013
  10 The time is Thu Dec 12 21:01:06 EST 2013
  10 The time is Thu Dec 12 21:01:07 EST 2013
   9 The time is Thu Dec 12 21:01:08 EST 2013
  10 The time is Thu Dec 12 21:01:09 EST 2013
   9 The time is Thu Dec 12 21:01:10 EST 2013
  10 The time is Thu Dec 12 21:01:11 EST 2013
  10 The time is Thu Dec 12 21:01:12 EST 2013
```

etc. No delays. Important to note - **I did not attempt to cut out the time**. Next, I did

```
tail -f a.txt | cut -f7 -d' ' | uniq -c
```

And your problem reproduced - it would "hang" for quite a while (until there was 4k of characters in the buffer, and then it would vomit it all out at once).

A bit of searching online ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/16823549/1967396 ) told me of a utility called [stdbuf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) . At that reference, it specifically mentions almost exactly your scenario, and they provide the following workaround (paraphrasing to match my scenario above):

```
tail -f a.txt | stdbuf -oL cut -f7 -d' ' | uniq -c
```

And that would be great… except that this utility doesn't exist on my machine (Mac OS) - it is specific to GNU coreutils. This left me unable to test - although it may be a good solution for you.

Never fear - I found the following workaround, based on the `socat` command (which I honestly barely understand, but I adapted from the answer given at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25377 ).

Make a small file called `tailcut.sh` (this is the "long_running_command" from the link above):

```
#!/bin/ksh
tail -f a.txt | cut -f7 -d' '
```

Give it execute permissions with `chmod 755 tailcut.sh` . Then issue the following command:

```
socat EXEC:./tailcut.sh,pty,ctty STDIO | uniq -c
```

And hey presto - your lumpy output is lumpy no more. The `socat` sends the output from the script straight to the next pipe, and `uniq` can do its thing.

Answer (score 4):

You may try `logtop`, (`apt-get install logtop`):

Usage:

```
tail -F /var/logs/request.log | [cut the date-time] | logtop
```

Example:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/varnish/varnishncsa.log  | awk '{print $4}' | logtop
5585 elements in 10 seconds (558.50 elements/s)
   1  690 69.00/s [28/Mar/2015:23:13:48
   2  676 67.60/s [28/Mar/2015:23:13:47
   3  620 62.00/s [28/Mar/2015:23:13:49
   4  576 57.60/s [28/Mar/2015:23:13:53
   5  541 54.10/s [28/Mar/2015:23:13:54
   6  540 54.00/s [28/Mar/2015:23:13:55
   7  511 51.10/s [28/Mar/2015:23:13:51
   8  484 48.40/s [28/Mar/2015:23:13:52
   9  468 46.80/s [28/Mar/2015:23:13:50
```

Columns are, from left to right:

- Just row number
- qte seen
- hits per second
- the actual line

Comment: Seems to me this answers a different question?

Comment: It seems that this is not a live feed - the output shows lines not in chronological order. I thought OP wanted to know the number of times a particular message was repeated _as it happens_.

Comment: logtop is live, but not chronologically ordered, but putting the bigger (number of occurences) first. That (often) make more sense.

Comment: I agree it is a good solution to the problem OP is probably trying to solve - but not a solution to the question posed. That's my only gripe. Personally I'm happy to learn about a new tool!

Answer (score 1):

Consider how `uniq -c` is working.

In order to print the count, it needs to read all the unique lines and only once a line that is different from the previous one, it can print the line and number of occurences.

That's just how the algorithm fundamentally works and there is no way around it.

You can test this by running

```
touch a
tail -F a | uniq -c
```

And then one after another

```
echo 1 >> a
echo 1 >> a
echo 1 >> a
```

nothing happens. Only after you run

```
echo 2 >> a
```

`uniq` can print there were 3 "1\n" occurences.

Comment: Of course. Still, I'd expect the log lines to be printed out when the date/time field changes, which happens every second! But it outputs in delay of more than one minute and in bulks, not live.